# How to set an textbox value to the number of elements in an array

Tags: vb.net

I'm in high school so I'm a beginner, but I am creating a program to calculate the probabilities of rolling a chosen value given by the user in a textbox, in another textbox, they will need to put the amount of times they want to roll the die, the problem is that it is only outputting 1 number at a time no matter what I do, here is my code so far

```
Public Class Form1

   Private Sub cmdGenerate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdGenerate.Click

    ' Initialize the random-number generator.
       Dim strOutput As String
       Dim intCounter As Integer
       Dim intArray(txtFirst.Text) As Integer
       Dim Random As Integer

       For intCounter = 1 To Val(txtFirst.Text)
           Randomize()
           Random = Int(Rnd() * 6) + 1

           intArray(intCounter) = Random
           strOutput = intArray(txtFirst.Text)

       Next intCounter

      txtSequence.Text = strOutput + txtSequence.Text
   End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite the value of `strOutput` with each iteration of the loop:

```
strOutput = intArray(txtFirst.Text)
```

So by the time you show it to the user, it will have only the last value:

```
txtSequence.Text = strOutput + txtSequence.Text
```

Maybe you meant to *append* to `strOutput` instead?:

```
strOutput = strOutput + intArray(txtFirst.Text)
```

Or perhaps put the last line (which already appends) inside the loop?:

```
    strOutput = intArray(txtFirst.Text)
    txtSequence.Text = strOutput + txtSequence.Text
Next intCounter
```

There are probably a number of different solutions.  Consider this a great opportunity to familiarize yourself with stepping through the code in a debugger.  There you can observe the runtime values and behavior, line by line, and see specifically where that behavior differs from what you expect.

Comment: Note that txtFirst.Text (apart from being a String instead of a number) indicates the maximum size of the array. I believe `intArray(txtFirst.Text)` should be `intArray(intCounter)`.

Answer (score 1):

Since all of your numbers are stored in an array, you don't need strOutput. The join function will concatenate all the items of the array.

```
txtSequence.Text = String.Join(",", intArray)
```

Also you don't need to start your variable with str/int.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this will fit your needs:

```
Textbox.Text = CStr(intArray.Length)
```